# Create a static lib from matlab code

Tags: c++, c, matlab, static-libraries, matlab-deployment

I'm already aware that you can create a stand alone executable and a shared lib from matlab. However, it would be better for our configuration management process (version and distribution) to use a static lib that then is included in the dll I'm building (in C++).

This may not be possible at all, but I'm curious. Has anyone done that before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little google-fu I found this: [Generating Static C/C++ Libraries from MATLAB Code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/coder/ug/bswnwje.html)

It looks like you can create them from projects or from the command line.